# How to resolve Module Not Found Error when customizing existing echart in Apache Superset?

Tags: reactjs, npm, apache-superset

I am running Superset 1.5.0 via `docker-compose`, and want to customize a chart belonging to `@superset-ui/plugin-chart-echarts`.

What I did was copy `plugin-chart-echarts` module into the `superset-frontend/src/visualizations` directory, and change the code in `superset-frontend/src/visualizations/presets/MainPreset.js` from:

```
import {
  BigNumberChartPlugin,
  BigNumberTotalChartPlugin,
  EchartsPieChartPlugin,
  EchartsBoxPlotChartPlugin,
  EchartsAreaChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesBarChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesLineChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesScatterChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesSmoothLineChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesStepChartPlugin,
  EchartsGraphChartPlugin,
  EchartsGaugeChartPlugin,
  EchartsRadarChartPlugin,
  EchartsFunnelChartPlugin,
  EchartsTreemapChartPlugin,
  EchartsMixedTimeseriesChartPlugin,
  EchartsTreeChartPlugin,
} from '@superset-ui/plugin-chart-echarts';
```

to:

```
import {
  BigNumberChartPlugin,
  BigNumberTotalChartPlugin,
  EchartsPieChartPlugin,
  EchartsBoxPlotChartPlugin,
  EchartsAreaChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesBarChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesLineChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesScatterChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesSmoothLineChartPlugin,
  EchartsTimeseriesStepChartPlugin,
  EchartsGraphChartPlugin,
  EchartsGaugeChartPlugin,
  EchartsRadarChartPlugin,
  EchartsFunnelChartPlugin,
  EchartsTreemapChartPlugin,
  EchartsMixedTimeseriesChartPlugin,
  EchartsTreeChartPlugin,
} from '../plugin-chart-echarts';
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up` with the `superset-node` service, I get the following error:

```
superset_node           | WARNING in ./node_modules/@data-ui/shared/esm/enhancer/WithTooltip.js 3:60-78
superset_node           | export 'withTooltipPropTypes' (imported as 'vxTooltipPropTypes') was not found in '@vx/tooltip/build/tooltips/TooltipWithBounds' (possible exports: __esModule, default)
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | WARNING in ./src/dashboard/components/Header/index.jsx 63:8-35
superset_node           | export 'UserWithPermissionsAndRoles' (imported as 'UserWithPermissionsAndRoles') was not found in 'src/types/bootstrapTypes' (module has no exports)
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | WARNING in ./src/components/Checkbox/index.tsx 19:0-74
superset_node           | export 'CheckboxProps' (reexported as 'CheckboxProps') was not found in 'src/components/Checkbox/Checkbox' (possible exports: default)
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | WARNING in ./src/components/Popover/index.tsx 20:0-48
superset_node           | export 'PopoverProps' (reexported as 'PopoverProps') was not found in 'antd/lib/popover' (possible exports: __esModule, default)
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | WARNING in ./src/components/Popover/index.tsx 21:0-52
superset_node           | export 'TooltipPlacement' (reexported as 'TooltipPlacement') was not found in 'antd/lib/tooltip' (possible exports: __esModule, default)
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | WARNING in ./src/utils/textUtils.ts 23:13-46
superset_node           | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../superset_text' in '/app/superset-frontend/src/utils'
superset_node           | 
superset_node           | ERROR in ./src/visualizations/presets/MainPreset.js 52:0-71:26
superset_node           | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../plugin-chart-echarts' in '/app/superset-frontend/src/visualizations/presets'
```

Why do I get `Module not found`  error? I have added `plugin-chart-echarts` module right outside /presets, which is the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Superset is not officially supported on Windows unfortunately.
Use:-
Mac OSX and Linux

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).